# Async loading external javascript widget after page has fully loaded while still having the embed code in the HTML body

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load a embeddable external javascript widget after the page has fully loaded, ie, when the page fully loads, the widget should load its content asyncronously. This is for the Google trends widget but i am sure the logic would be similar for others as well.
I tried this

```
<script src="stoploading.js"></script>
<style onload="ytb()"></style>
<div class="trends">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/680_RC25/embed_loader.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("GEO_MAP", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"Olympics","geo":"","time":"all"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {});
</script>
</div>
<script src="startloading.js"></script>
```

stoploading.js

```
function ytb(){
    googletrends = document.querySelector('.trends').innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('.trends').innerHTML = "";   
}
```

startloading.js

```
window.onload = function(){
document.querySelector('.trends').innerHTML = googletrends;
}
```

Now this kind of works in Firefox but it only loads half the widget for some reason.
In Chrome, it doesn't load anything and gives this error:

```
(program):1 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:9292".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

So what is the right way of doing it. Please note that I need the widget to be present in the HTML body while the page loads as well.

Comment: If you want the content to load after the page loads, this is called syncrhonous not asynchronous.  If you want to update the content after the page has loaded as content becomes available, this would be a synchronous action (page load) followed by an asynchronous action (retrieve content to display).  Is this the correct interpretation of your problem?

Comment: @Dreamwalker sorry yes i may have used the wrong term. I just want to load it after the page is done loading. but after the page has loaded and it starts loading the external js widget, the browser's wheel shouldn't go round, it should stop after the main page has loaded - if you know what i mean :)

Comment: The browser wheel turning is just communicating that the page is still processing an object (in your case a javascript to retrieve data).  Since the script should be looping infinitely to check for updates to the feed, it makes sense the browser would indicate this.

Comment: @Dreamwalker i understand what you mean. If I run this in Firefox, it works just the way i want, the page loads but the wheel doesn't go round once the page is done loading and then it loads the trends widget and the widget then appears in place. But it only shows the widget in half size and it doesn't work at all in Chrome, which is the problem.

Comment: @Dreamwalker Maybe 'defer' ing the widget is the right word?

Comment: If it is working in one browser but not another, it is more likely an issue with the browser.  A feature in Chrome is not always available in Firefox, and vice-versa for all browsers.  You can check the browser capatibility to see if Chrome allows/enables the CSS, Javascript, HTML, etc.